# Angular update view only if the properties of the object has changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, ngrx

I'm polling data every 15 seconds from my web api in my angular application. This is causing my angular material expansion panel to go back to its not expanded default position and its slowing down the website, which is causing inconvenience for the user. Is there a way for me to just update the view if the data I'm using to update the view differs from the view's current data?

Below is the code for my component.

```
              //component.html

                <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of vehicleDetail?.histalarm" class="expansion-panel">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <p class="mobil-font-size">
                            <!-- The date is highlighted in the color of the severity of the alarm-->
                            <span [ngClass]="getDetailColors(item.severity)"> {{ item.timestamp}} </span>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;"> - Description: </span> {{ item.description }}.
                        </p>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <!-- All extra info is being displayed below. Translators is used for kind and severity
                    to make them more readable-->
                    <p>
                        <span class="bold"> More Information </span>
                        <br>
                        <span class="bold"> Severity: </span> {{ severityTranslator(item.severity) }}
                        <br>
                        <span class="bold"> Details: </span> {{item.details }}
                    </p>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
```

In my component.ts Im using ngrx store to get my data from the web api.
vehicleDetail is the selected vehicle, and vehicleDetail?.histalarm" is used to loop over the list of alarms that exist for a vehicle.

---

```
// component.ts
ngOnInit() {
   // init vehicles details
    this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicleDetails).subscribe(data => {
      this.vehicleDetails = data;
      this.setMarkers(this.selected);
      this.updateFavoriteVehicles();
    });
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicleDetails());
}
```

My biggest concern at the moment is the fact that the expansion panel keeps being updated as the user tries to read the details. This is happening because I told the expansion panel to be updated every 15 seconds, since there is timestamps and other things I wish to be updated. The constant interruption is frustrating however and that is what I'm trying to solve.

#### Edit

Posting the code for the reducer as well as requested

```
import * as fromVehicleDetails from '../actions/vehicledetails.action';
import { VehicleDetail } from '../../models/vehicle-detail';

export interface VehicleDetailsState {
  entities: { [id: number]: VehicleDetail };
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: VehicleDetailsState = {
  entities: {},
  loaded: false,
  loading: false
};

export function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: fromVehicleDetails.VehicleDetailsAction
): VehicleDetailsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case fromVehicleDetails.LOAD_VEHICLEDETAILS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    }
    case fromVehicleDetails.LOAD_VEHICLEDETAILS_SUCCESS: {
      const vehicledetails = action.payload;
      const entities = vehicledetails.reduce(
        (
          entity: { [id: number]: VehicleDetail },
          vehicledetail: VehicleDetail
        ) => {
          return {
            ...entity,
            [vehicledetail.id]: vehicledetail
          };
        },
        {
          ...state.entities
        }
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
        entities
      };
    }
    case fromVehicleDetails.LOAD_VEHICLEDETAILS_FAIL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        loading: false
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
}

export const getVehicleDetailsEntities = (state: VehicleDetailsState) =>
  state.entities;
export const getVehicleDetailsLoaded = (state: VehicleDetailsState) =>
  state.loaded;
export const getVehicleDetailsLoading = (state: VehicleDetailsState) =>
  state.loading;
```

Comment: Can we see the component code ?

Comment: can you provide relevant code  so that we can help you out here ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Raph and CruelEngine, its updated. Please let me know if you want me to post any more relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried distinctUntilChanged operator? 
check this [link](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#managing-updates-with-distinctuntilchanged). it may help

Comment: Can you post the code of your NGRX reducer which updates the data received from the API into the state?

Comment: @MarkHughes Of course. Its updated. And I will check that out Nikhil! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @maac - I can see the problem now, answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are replacing the object in your state each time the data is refreshed. This means that NGRX will notify any subscribers to selects of that object that it has changed, which means Angular will re-draw the UI because the observable has emitted.

What you need to do to avoid the extra re-draws will be to assess in your reducer whether the details have changed or not, then return an updated state only if the details have changed. To calculate whether the details have changed, you will need to do a "deep equality" check on the data returned from the API against the data currently in the state, for example:

```
 case fromVehicleDetails.LOAD_VEHICLEDETAILS_SUCCESS: {
      const vehicledetails = action.payload;
      const entities = vehicledetails.reduce(
        (
          entity: { [id: number]: VehicleDetail },
          vehicledetail: VehicleDetail
        ) => {
          return {
            ...entity,
            [vehicledetail.id]: vehicledetail
          };
        },
        {
          ...state.entities
        }
      );

      // Add logic to check if entities has changed, and not return the updated entities if they have not:
      if (deepEqual(entities, state.entities)) return { ...state, loaded: true, loading: false };

      // Entities have changed, return updated state with new entities:        
      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
        entities: entities
      };
    }
```

Then you'll need to implement a deepEquals function to assess whether the new and old entities are the same or not. Libraries like [lodash have operators for doing this](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) or you could write your own specific check knowing the properties and things that can change on refresh.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply! The timestamp will always be updated and therefore each object will differ from the previous one. Is there a way for me to get around this? Because I would like to update the timestamp continuously. Or is this impossible since the two properties belong to the same object?

Comment: If you want the timestamp to be updated on display, obviously you'll have to update the object and you cannot avoid the redraw. If you don't care about the timestamp, you could delete it from the vehicledetail object when doing your reduce (e.g. `delete vehicledetail.timestamp` before the return line in the `reduce` callback).

Comment: The other option would be to factor the "last updated timestamp" into a different tree and select that separately, so if the timestamps change but the other details do not, you can keep the same object for the details. @maac